# ObserveSingleEventOfType(ChildAdded) only return one snapshot Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 `FirDataSnapshot`. When I am using `observeEventType(.ChildAdded,..)`, it returns 3 item. When I use `observeSingeEventTypeOf`, it returns only 1 snapshot. I don't know why.

Comment: PLease provide some code so that everyone knws what you are talking about and is able to find issues within the code

Answer (score 2):

`observeSingleEventType` returns single value means it observe `.childAdded` only once ...  the block is immediately canceled after the initial data is returned.

If you are using `observeEventType` than it gets all values from database ..

Comment: so it only gets back one value? I have 3 values, if it only get back once and it is cancelled, shouldn't it get back 3 values?

Comment: observeSingleEventType .. observe only one time ... so it gives back only one child

Comment: it gives back 3 values if you use `observeEventType` not `observeSingleEventTy‌​pe`

Comment: @Unknown if this clear your doubts please accept my answer by click check mark below  voting counter